# jQuery Date Picker - disable past dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to have a date Range select using the UI date picker.

in the from/to field people should not be able to view or select dates previous to the present day.

This is my code:

```
$(function() {
    var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
});
```

Can some one tell me how to disable dates previous the to the present date.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You must create a new date object and set it as `minDate` when you initialize the datepickers

```
<label for="from">From</label> <input type="text" id="from" name="from"/> <label for="to">to</label> <input type="text" id="to" name="to"/>

var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    minDate: dateToday,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
        dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
    }
});
```

Edit - from your comment now it works as expected http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/dAyzq/1/

Comment: i want to implement a way that people should not be able to pick a date which has been past.. like yesterday day before etc. Only from today and onwards.

Comment: @HarshaMV i updated my answer, you should just set minDate when you initialize the datepickers

Comment: You can add `showAnim:"",` to datepicker settings to remove annoying month and year changing when You make Your selection.

Comment: I used your script, but I am getting error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". how will I fix this?

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti This is exactly what I need, but can this be used in asp:Textbox? I tried but its not working, is there any specific change that I should do? Thank you in advance

Comment: @wolfQueen it depend a little on your markup, in theory it should work asp

Answer (score 83):

Declare dateToday variable and use Date() function to set it..
then use that variable to assign to minDate which is parameter of datepicker.

```
var dateToday = new Date(); 
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        minDate: dateToday
    });
});
```

That's it...  Above answer was really helpful...  keep it up guys..

Answer (score 51):

```
$('#datepicker-dep').datepicker({
    minDate: 0
});
```

`minDate:0` works for me.

Answer (score 23):

Use the "minDate" option to restrict the earliest allowed date.
The value "0" means today (0 days from today):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtdate").datepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            // ...
        });
    });
```

Docs here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

Answer (score 8):

Just to add to this:

If you also need to **prevent the user to manually type** a date in the past, this is a possible solution. This is what we ended up doing (based on @Nicola Peluchetti's answer)

```
var dateToday = new Date();

$("#myDatePickerInput").change(function () {
    var updatedDate = $(this).val();
    var instance = $(this).data("datepicker");
    var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, updatedDate, instance.settings);

    if (date < dateToday) {
        $(this).datepicker("setDate", dateToday);
    }
});
```

What this does is to change the value to today's date if the user manually types a date in the past.

Answer (score 7):

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dAyzq/722/) ,try this,

```
    $('#from').datepicker(
     { 
        minDate: 0,
        beforeShow: function() {
        $(this).datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $('#to').val());
      }
   });
  $('#to').datepicker(
     {
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        beforeShow: function() {
        $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', $('#from').val());
        if ($('#from').val() === '') $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', 0);                             
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 7):

This is easy way to do this

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setStartDate', new Date());
```

also we can disable future days

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setEndDate', new Date());
```

Answer (score 5):

By setting `startDate: new Date()`

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    ...
    startDate: new Date(),
});
```

Answer (score 4):

set startDate attribute of datepicker, it works, below is the working code

```
$(function(){
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    startDate: '-0m'
    //endDate: '+2d'
}).on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $('#sDate1').text($('#datepicker').data('date'));
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('hide');
});
})
```

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery API documentation - datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)

The minimum selectable date. When set to `null`, there is no minimum.

**Multiple types supported:**

**Date:** A date object containing the minimum date.
**Number:** A number of days from today. For example `2` represents `two days` from today and `-1` represents `yesterday`.
**String:** A string in the format defined by the `dateFormat` option, or a relative date.
Relative dates must contain value and period pairs; valid periods are `y` for `years`, `m` for `months`, `w` for `weeks`, and `d` for `days`. For example, `+1m +7d` represents `one month and seven days` from `today`.

In order not to display previous dates other than today

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({minDate: 0});
```

Answer (score 3):

just replace your code:

old code:

```
$("#dateSelect").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'

});
```

new code:

```
$("#dateSelect").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: 0
});
```

Answer (score 2):

"**mindate**" attribute should be used to disable passed dates in jquery datepicker.

> minDate: new Date() Or minDate: '0' is the key for this.

```
Ex:

$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({minDate: new Date()});
});
```

OR

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({minDate: 0});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use

```
startDate: 'today'
```

it working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have created function to disable previous date, disable flexible weekend days (Like Saturday, Sunday)

We are using **beforeShowDay**  method of jQuery UI datepicker plugin.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
var NotBeforeToday = function(date) {
  var now = new Date(); //this gets the current date and time
  if (date.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() == now.getMonth() && date.getDate() >= now.getDate() && (date.getDay() > 0 && date.getDay() < 6) )
   return [true,""];
  if (date.getFullYear() >= now.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() > now.getMonth() && (date.getDay() > 0 && date.getDay() < 6))
   return [true,""];
  if (date.getFullYear() > now.getFullYear() && (date.getDay() > 0 && date.getDay() < 6))
   return [true,""];
  return [false,""];
 }


jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: NotBeforeToday
    });
```

[image]

Here today's date is 15th Sept. I have disabled Saturday and Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare current date into variables like this

```
 $(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    var currentDate = date.getDate();
    var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate)
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#date" ).datetimepicker({startDate:new Date()}).datetimepicker('update', new Date());
```

`new Date()` : function get the todays date
previous date are locked.
100% working