# Datepicker should display dates from the next month only..Restrict current month dates to be unselectable

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a following requirement: the datepicker should display dates starting from next month.

For example if current month is january, then it should display dates from first day of February and if it is February it should display dates from 1st of March. In all conditions the current month dates should be unselectable or hidden.

Plz help me how can i acheive this functionality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356358/jquery-date-picker-disable-past-dates Use the search button before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery date picker supports this functionality out of the box.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dateThis").datepicker({minDate: "+1M"});
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RXpCT/).