# adding restriction on selecting previous date in a datepicker

Tags: asp.net, datepicker

I am using asp.net code where datepicker is used to enter date. I want some code so that previous date cannot be selected and entered by the datepicker. How can I put the restriction.

```
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
   <script>
    $(function() {
     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
     });
    </script>
   </head>
    <body>

    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>


    </body>
    </html>
```

please tell me any asp.net code

Comment: what about using `session` to save your previous selected date ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356358/jquery-date-picker-disable-past-dates here is your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

minimum date can select from last 20 days

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
});
```

Comment: yeah its working when I did some changes. thanks a lot@sangram parmar

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -0, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
});
```