# disable dates from datepicker using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

how to disable dates from date picker following code

```
<input class="datepicker input-small" type="text" id="dpd1" required>
```

js code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            "autoclose": true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: suggest you to read API documentation here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ and go through examples here: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: which dates you want to disable from the datepicker?

Comment: i want to disable past dates till today

Comment: Possible duplicat [jQuery Date Picker - disable past dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356358/jquery-date-picker-disable-past-dates/9978261#9978261)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="datepicker input-small" type="text" id="dpd1" required>
```

js code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
         minDate: 0 

    });

});
```

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
         minDate: new Date(2013, 10, 21),

    });

});

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { $('.datepicker').datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2013, 10, 21), }); }); 



If this is not working, then check error in firebug.

Comment: not working error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

Comment: So, "jquery.datepicker.js" Scipt  is not getting to your HTML code.. Check path properly.. You can check script path under "NET" Tab in firebug..

Comment: i checked the pat it is correct .. see to the error         (anonymous 
p.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:2
g.handle.h jquery.min.js:2
p.event.trigger jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:2
p.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
p.fn.p.each jquery.min.js:2
p.fn.extend.trigger jquery.min.js:2
p.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function)