# User cant Select Previous Date jQuery-ui Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

Hi Friends How to restrict user to not select previous date then the date selected before by him in same form Below is my code

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
          <td align="right">Check in date</td>
          <td width="81%" style="padding:0;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
              <td width="25%"><input type="text" name="ww" size="30" id="checkIn" class="nameBook"/></td>
              <td width="15%" align="right">Check out date*</td>
              <td width="60%"><input type="text" name="ww2" size="30" id="checkOut" class="nameBook"/></td>

            </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#checkIn" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0,  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"}); 
        var checkIn = $( "#checkIn" ).val();
        $( "#checkIn" ).on('change',function(){
             alert(checkInDate);                
        })
    $( "#checkOut" ).datepicker({ minDate: /*Not Lasser then the date which user selects in #checkIn*/ });
});
</script>
```

Please help me guys...

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Date Picker - disable past dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356358/jquery-date-picker-disable-past-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on selection you can change the mindate

```
onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
  }
```