# How to inactive previous date in Bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using Bootstrap datepicker and I want to inactive previous date. Means the user should not be able to select the previous day. I want this to develop functionality to schedule some users work.

What I need to do?

Comment: Exactly *which* datepicker are you using?  Do you have any code?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356358/jquery-date-picker-disable-past-dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will disable date after today.

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);                    
$('#myId').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() > now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks sir,
It is exactly what i want and is working.
I was trying for the following

<input type="text" id="scheduleDate" placeholder="Select Date" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" size="16" class="input-sm form-control datepicker">

Thanks again!

Comment: @VaibhavV.Joshi   Thanks 

Please mark as answer..If you wish :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#Date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy', minDate: 0 });
```