# How could I disable past dates in php datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, html, date, datepicker

How could I disable the old dates from the present date in the datepicker using a function script? Thank you!

**booknow.php**

```
        <html>
        <body>
        <label for="shootdate">Desired Date:</label>
        <input required type="date" name="shootdate" id="shootdate" title="Choose your desired date"/>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: search on google : `disable previous dates in datepicker`. you will definitely get the answer

Comment: Yes. What should I do? :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053119/how-to-inactive-previous-date-in-bootstrap-datepicker/25053271#25053271

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <label for="shootdate">Desired Date:</label>
        <input required type="date" name="shootdate" id="shootdate" title="Choose your desired date" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can do this using PHP itself. We can easily set minimum date to today, so that user cannot select previous dates.

Or, if you need it only using jquery, give a try on this

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
     $( function() {
       $( "#shootdate" ).datepicker({
        minDate: 0
       });
     });
    </script>
 </head>
    <body>
     <label for="shootdate">Desired Date:</label>
     <input required type="text" name="shootdate" id="shootdate" title="Choose your desired date" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just simply have to set the datepicker option when initializing. The option `minDate` needs to be setup in order to do that.

Initialize you datepicker like this:

```
jQuery('#shootdate').datepicker({
         minDate: 0
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<label for="from">From</label> <input type="text" id="from" name="from"/> 
<label for="to">to</label> <input type="text" id="shootdate" name="to"/>

var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $("#from, #shootdate").datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 3,
minDate: dateToday,
onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
    var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
        instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
    dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
}
```

});

Comment: Not working :( Where does the "FROM" and "TO" came from? I dont get it huhuhu :(

Comment: I don't understand all the jQuery answers. The OP hasn't used a jQuery tag, hasn't mentioned in the OP and hasn't included it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>

 <script>
 $(function() {
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: The datepicker is not functioning :(

Comment: how you are using ?...You have to use Jquery extension.

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Using an input type date, you can set the minimum date using the *min* attribute. However, not all browsers in use support input type date (see [MDN support matrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)), so you'll need a fallback.

```js
function getISODate(){
  var d = new Date();
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' + 
          ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
          ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2);
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('minToday').setAttribute('min',getISODate());
}
```

```html
Select date (must be on or after 20-Feb-2017)<input type="date" min="2017-02-20">
<br>
Select date(must be on or after today)<input type="date" id="minToday">
```