# Disable datepicker past date & time

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

I'm using datepicker and i like people not be able to select date and time previous to the present day. I used "minDate: 0" to disable the past date but is there a way to disable past time. For example, if the current time is 5am, i do not want people to select 3 or 4 am of the same day.

This is my code:

```
var dt;
dt = 
$('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
    inline:true,
    minDate: 0,
    format:'m/d/Y H:i',
    formatDate:'d/m/Y'
});
```

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356358/jquery-date-picker-disable-past-dates

Comment: hello sir did you get the answer

Answer (score 2):

Declare `dateToday` variable and use `Date()` function to set it.
Then use that variable to assign to `minDate` which is parameter of `datepicker`.

```
var dateToday = new Date(); 
$(function() {
    $( "#datetimepicker3" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        minDate: dateToday
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi madhu, basically `minDate: 0` already disables the past date. But it doesn't disable the past time. For example, if the current time is 5 am, i like to disable even 4 am of the same day. :)

Comment: Yes, it disabled date correctly. How to disable the past time?

Answer (score 2):

To disable past dates you need to define min to today date like this:-

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
        min: new Date()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the `minDate` value to `dateToday` just like this

```
var dt; 
dt = 
$('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
    inline:true,
    minDate: dateToday,
    format:'m/d/Y H:i',
    formatDate:'d/m/Y'
});
```

Comment: Disable past TIME.  Please be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the past time, you should use `minDateTime`. 
Update your code like this,

```
var dt = new Date();
$('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
    inline:true,
    minDate: 0,
    minDateTime: dt,
    format:'m/d/Y H:i',
    formatDate:'d/m/Y'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this:

```
$(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
                     minDate: moment()


                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://www.thecodedeveloper.com/disable-past-date-time/)

i was facing same problem disable Past date time with DateTimePicker jQuery plugin. but i have found solution for it-

```
var checkPastTime = function(currentDateTime) {

var d = new Date();
var todayDate = d.getDate();

// 'this' is jquery object datetimepicker
if (currentDateTime.getDate() == todayDate) { // check today date
    this.setOptions({
        minTime: d.getHours() + ':00' //here pass current time hour
    });
} else
    this.setOptions({
        minTime: false
    });
};

$('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
    format:'Y-m-d H:i',
    minDate : 0,
    onChangeDateTime:checkPastTime,
    onShow:checkPastTime
});
```

[demo](https://www.thecodedeveloper.com/disable-past-date-time/)