# I want to disable the past time in datetimepicker in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

i have 2 views. one of them calls the other one for the script of the datetime picker. right now what i get is a datetime picker that had past dates disabled. what i want to get is a date picker that not only has past date disabled but also has the passed time disabled. i am posting my code below.

This is my first view where the datepicker is displayed.

```
<input class="field-input form_datetime_houseboat" type="text" readonly placeholder="Starting Date" name="fromdate" id="fromdate">
```

my 2nd view has the section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nowDate = new Date();
    var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var dt = new Date();
    var timed = new Date(dt.getHours(), dt.getMinutes());

    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({format: 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii', startDate:today, minTime: timed});

    </script>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: i also tried the following code segment:  timed.setTime(timed.getTime());

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356358/jquery-date-picker-disable-past-dates

Comment: Add maxDate: 2,  will help you

Comment: sorry.. it doesn't work....i am still able to select past time say 10:00 when the date is 7th jan 2016 (today's date)

Comment: Try - $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});   (similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356358/jquery-date-picker-disable-past-dates)

Comment: @user2947,Maha Dev, isn't that the solution to disable past date?

Answer (score 0):

try this script :helps to disable previoue date and time. create new date object as  minDate

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.simple-dtpicker.js"></script>// datetime picker 

<div id="date_picker"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $('#date_picker').dtpicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    minDate: dateToday,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
    var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
    instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
        dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
    }
});
});
</script>
```