# how to add datepicker for a field in apex5.0

Tags: oracle-apex-5

i'm new to apex and struggling to add a datepicker on a date field for an interactive report.
How can i add the datepicker or make the field inputable 'DD-MM-YYYY' that will insert into the table and also add validation to make it accept only the system date?
Please help!

Comment: What have you tried? What is your code so far?

Comment: I did The report call another form for input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interactive Reports are not editable in Oracle APEX 5. So, you will have to make use of Tabular Form instead of Interactive Report and then you can add DatePicker column type. You can even add custom validations to tabular forms.

If you are using APEX 5.1, then you can take advantage of Interactive Grid which will let you edit report data and also add validations.

There is a packaged application, "Sample Master Detail" that is shipped with APEX 5 which demonstrates these functionalities. Here are screenshots of the app and the master detail form that has an example of tabular form with editable column with date picker,

[image: Sample Master Detail Packaged Application]

[image: Department Master Detail Form]

Comment: Wht sample application are there?

Comment: There are many packaged application but the one that you might be interested in is Sample Master Detail application. I have updated my answers with screenshots of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Just add APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP in your region select query.

```
select col1, col2, 
APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP(4,rownum,sysdate,'dd-mon-yyyy') hd
from YOUR_TABLE
```

For more info look at apex documentation: [APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_item.htm#AEAPI194)

If you need just to format column as input, use html expression in report column properties:

```
<input type="text" value="#COLUMN_NAME#">
```

Comment: Workiing.. txs wht ur email add

Comment: How to add validation in the Datepicker not to enter date < sysdate?

Comment: One option is to format column as input, create dynamic action on page load and use example in this post: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356358/jquery-date-picker-disable-past-dates

Answer (score 0):

use the APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP2 Property you have get actual date picker

Comment: thnks wat ur email add?