# How to insert validation in datepicker interactive report in apex5.0

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I have one field :P2_DATE, datepicker on an interactive report in apex5.0.

First Question:
How can i create validation thru: 
1. A dynamic action
2. A validation process
that gives an error msg: 'Date should not be greater than system date'
when user choose from datepicker.

Second Question:
How to show only today's date in the date picker and disable others dates.

Pls provide steps-by-steps instruction if possible...thxs!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Validation
2. Set type to PL/SQL Expression and put:

   to_date(:P2_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') = to_date(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY')

You can see this Answer:[jQuery Date Picker - disable past dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356358/jquery-date-picker-disable-past-dates) for disable dates in datepicker but you already have control over date by validation. 
Another way is to create custom datepicker from external plugin.