# How to disable previous date in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code i am using timezone of pacific/Auckland as per their timezone today date i.e.,11-April-2017 is completed now their date is 12-April-2017 but in my date picker 11th April is not disabled. I need to disable previous date i.e., is 11-April-2017.

This is my datepicker code

```
.datepicker({
               autoclose: true,
               todayHighlight: true,
               startDate: new Date().toLocaleString('en-NZ', { timeZone: 'Pacific/Auckland' })
             })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Date Picker - disable past dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356358/jquery-date-picker-disable-past-dates)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just by sustracting one day from today's date(new Date()) in startDate attribute.

Try this to substract one day from today's date in client side;

```
.datepicker({
           autoclose: true,
           todayHighlight: true,
           startDate: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1).toLocaleString('en-NZ', { timeZone: 'Pacific/Auckland' })
         })
```

Comment: are you sure it is not a browser cache issue?

Comment: it cleaned browser cache also till it is not working

Comment: I have updated my answer, now check please. Notice the change "- 1"(minus) to "+ 1"(plus)

Comment: still it is not working and it is enabled all previous dates also

Answer (score 1):

The [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) option is what you are looking for.

```
.datepicker({
       autoclose: true,
       todayHighlight: true,
       minDate: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1).toLocaleString('en-NZ', { timeZone: 'Pacific/Auckland' })
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create it with `minDate`:

```
.datepicker({
       autoclose: true,
       todayHighlight: true,
       minDate: // whatever you choose,
       startDate: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1).toLocaleString('en-NZ', { timeZone: 'Pacific/Auckland' })
     })
```

Comment: it is not working and it is enabled previous dates also

Comment: @ArunRaju the problem may be the format for the date you are entering

Comment: i am using mm/dd/yyyy