# How to disable previous dates in calendar javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, calendar

I am trying to disable previous dates in calendar. I am using this code like

My **HTML** code is below.

```
<input type="text" required name="date_from" name="date_from" class="mydate input-text full-width" placeholder="Departure Date" />
```

My **script** code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".mydate").datepicker({
       format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
       autoclose: true
   });
    $(".flexslider").flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: true,
        directionNav: false,
        slideshow: true,
        slideshowSpeed: 5000
    });
</script>
```

It shows calendar without previous dates disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set minDate option while applying datepicker.

Try This,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".mydate").datepicker({
       format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
       autoclose: true,
       minDate: 0,   
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$( ".mydate" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `bootstrap date picker`. These are files to include

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Use this code to disable previous dates

HTML Input field

`<input id="date" data-provide="datepicker" name="date_from" >`

JAVASCRIPT

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate());

$('#date').datepicker({ 
startDate: date
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set minDate in initialization on datepicker

```
minDate:new Date()


$(".mydate").datepicker({
       format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
       autoclose: true,
       minDate:new Date()
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the minDate option. Example + fiddle on this forum:

[jQuery Date Picker - disable past dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356358/jquery-date-picker-disable-past-dates)

Answer (score 0):

As from your format may be you are using bootstrap date picker. So use `startDate` to disable previous dates

```
$(".mydate").datepicker({
       format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
       startDate: new Date(),
       autoclose: true
   });
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer mr. Desai

Comment: Glad to help @nirvi. If solution help you then you can upvote this for future  reader help

Answer (score 0):

Try this code... this will restrict the user if user submits form with date less than today's date then shows alert message to change the date.

**HTML Code**

```
    <form name="myform" onsubmit="return validateDateOfAppointment()">
    <input type="date" name="Date of Appointment" placeholder="Date of Appointment" id="Date" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
function validateDateOfAppointment(){
        var date=document.getElementById("Date").value;
        var d=new Date();
        var x=d.getFullYear()+"-"+(d.getMonth()+1)+"-"+d.getDate();
        var checkDate=date.substr(8,2);
        var equalDate=d.getDate();
        var checkMonth=date.substr(5,2);
        var equalMonth=d.getMonth();
        var checkYear=date.substr(0,4);
        var equalYear=d.getFullYear();
        if(checkMonth>=equalMonth){
            if(checkDate<equalDate){
            alert("Date cannot be less than today!! ");
            return false;
            }
        }
        else if(checkMonth<equalMonth){
            if(checkYear<equalYear){
                alert("Date cannot be less than today!! ");
                return false;
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: 1) why not just new Date("date from input").getTime() -  new Date().getTime() ?
2) you should use onchange even or something like that ?

Comment: I used this code in a form submission where the user has to enter only present date and future dates only.......Now i added some more code for giving more clarification.. I used "onsubmit" for checking correct date during form submission.   for 1) we get the date from user as a string so we cannot retrieve the  time or date directly from that so I used string methods for getting date,month and year